# Saving a 16 bit PNG using script

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to bake displacements using script but need to save the result using a 16 bit image format (such as PNG-16). How can I change the color-depth setting using script?

Example code

```
img = bpy.data.images.new(name="depthmap", width=imageSize,height=imageSize,alpha=False, float_buffer=True)
img.colorspace_settings.name = 'Linear'
# bake() #implemented in separate function
img.file_format = 'PNG'
# need to set to 16-bit here
img.filepath_raw = "my_new_bake.png"
img.save()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not directly assign the color depth on the image. However, you can make a scene and set its `render.image_settings.color_depth`. Then use `save_render()` with that scene to save the image with the color depth.

```
import bpy

# Create new scene to set color depth on it
scene = bpy.data.scenes.new('scene name')
settings = scene.render.image_settings
settings.color_depth = '16'
settings.file_format = 'PNG'

# Create new image and save with scene
img = bpy.data.images.new('name', width, height)
img.save_render('filepath', scene)
```

Comment: Awsome :) It works :)

Comment: +1 -- it works! But it's weird that why here 16 needs to be a string, whereas, for example, `scene.render.resolution_x` can be just an integer...

Comment: the bit-depth is a preset option.  For example, a bit-depth of 7 simply won't work.  That's why there is no point to make the option taking in an int value.  Else, maybe it's for the safety that someone will try to put in an int 7, and cause the computer to "Blow up" because an actual bit-depth of 7 is impossible.(It can be faked using a bit depth 8 or higher, but will always take up 8 bits amount of data per pixel/channel, unless you've written your own bit-packing algorithm to pack the 7 bit-depth image into a 8 bit data array.)

Comment: Please note that if you have a `File Output` node in your scene's composition, you need to set the `color_depth`, `color_mode`, and `file_format` specifically for that `File Output` node. Setting it globally will not work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Blender 3.3 and 3.6 will save 16-bit PNG files as expected when using the `float_buffer=True` option.

The following code is a quick test:

```py
import bpy
import numpy as np

# Random values
data = np.random.rand(128, 128, 4).astype(np.float32)

# Blender image
# https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.new
blender_image = bpy.data.images.new("OutputImage", width=data.shape[0], height=data.shape[1], alpha=False, float_buffer=True, is_data=True)

# Image content
blender_image.pixels = data.flatten()

# Save PNG
blender_image.filepath_raw = "/Users/jeinselen/Desktop/output_image_2.png"
blender_image.file_format = 'PNG'
blender_image.save()
```

The current scene bit depth does not change the output, and there doesn't seem to be any need to specify the bit depth manually. When `float_buffer` is set to `False` the saved file is 8-bit, when `float_buffer` is set to `True` the saved file is 16-bit.

Updated code from the original post, using `is_data` instead of `colorspace_settings`:

```py
img = bpy.data.images.new("depthmap", width=imageSize, height=imageSize, alpha=False, float_buffer=True, is_data=True)
# bake() #implemented in separate function
img.file_format = 'PNG'
img.filepath_raw = "my_new_bake.png"
img.save()
```